# Xcode adding DTXcode key and others to Info.plist

Tags: xcode, info.plist

Recently Xcode started adding keys to the Info.plist of my Cocoa app:

- DTXcode
- DTXcodeBuild
- DTCompiler
- DTPlatformBuild
- DTPlatformName
- DTPlatformVersion
- DTSDKBuild
- DTSDKName

What are those keys used for and why do they all of a sudden appear? Are they needed?

I'm using Xcode 3.2.6

Answer (score 3):

These keys serve as information about the development environment.

Fox example, Xcode add them when you code-sign your application before submitting it to the App Store.

They also appear in the binary details of the application on [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/).

Comment: Are they required for something in particular?

Comment: No, I don't know any usage where they are required. As they are not documented, I consider them as Apple specific keys that can change without further notice.